# asp.net compare validator

Tags: asp.net, validation

In the ASP.net, in the form like Password Reset, when we compare the new password and confirm password, if both are not matched we can display the Error Message like,

```
ErrorMessage="*Password not matched"
```

by using the Error Message property, the same way is it possible to display the Success Message like `"Password Matched"` after losing focus from the New password TextBox, in the UI part itself.

Comment: It may be possible but then you will be using a Validator for the wrong purpose. I would suggest to implement this with alternative methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message usually appears when the validation fails. Therefore, it stops the form from submitting. I would avoid changing this behavior, instead give feedback with a label, a popup, etc...